# How to order structure instances based on the value of a member

Tags: c, logic

I'm trying to make an algorithm for cars passing through an intersection. I'm currently having problems on deciding which car is supposed to cross depending on other cars's priority.

Here's an example code of what I'm doing

```
int main(void)
{
    struct Cars{
        int priority;
    };

    struct Cars c1;
    struct Cars c2;
    struct Cars c3;
    struct Cars c4;

    c1.priority=2;
    c2.priority=1;
    c3.priority=3;
    c4.priority=0;

    int Priorities[4] = {c1.priority,c2.priority,c3.priority,c4.priority};

    int Order[4];
}
```

What I am trying to do is trying to figure how to fill the Order array with the id of the car that is next to pass.
As in this example I want the Order array to be [4,2,1,3]. 0 being highest priority, 3 lowest

Although you could help me even more if you can help me figure out WHICH CAR has 
which priority so I could write some if's like:

```
if(the car with priority 0 has passed AND the car with priority 1 has passed)
{
    car with priority 2 can pass
}
```

Comment: Use a counter and linked lists.

Comment: Sorry I dont quite get it. How can a list help me here?

Comment: A *linked* list. If you have a list where each structure has a pointer to the next structure (in order of priority) your job will be much easier.

Comment: There are many ways to approach this problem. You should give more of the context it arises in—show the course assignment you were given. A simple way to approach it is to write code that goes through a list of the `Cars` and compares each one to the best one so far. When it finds a car with a greater claim to priority than the best so far, it updates the best so far.…

Comment: … More complicated approaches include sorting the list of cars by the priority of their claim, maintaining a list in sorted order and inserting new cars in the list in their appropriate position, and using more sophisticated data structures to maintain information about order. Which you should use depends on where you are in your studies, what the course is teaching, and what the specific assignment is.

Comment: To start, though, it would probably be helpful to write a function that takes two parameters, a `struct Cars A` and a `struct Cars B`, and returns a value that indicates whether, between just `A` and `B`, `A` should go first or `B` should go first.

Comment: Also think about how you want to handle when cars pass through the intersection. Are they removed from the list and the job then is just picking a car from those remaining in the list? Or are they kept in the list but marked in some way as having passed through? In the latter case, how does that affect the function I suggested in my previous comment?

Comment: When the car is done passing the intersection, another variable of the object changes and the state of the car is set in another way, but the priority doesnt change.
This is an embedded application, for a computer engineering assignment.
There are 4 cars in the intersection, and the rule of determining which car gets which priority to pass is determined by the order of the cars that reached the intersection. This isnt too important though

Comment: The function that compares the priorities of two cars sounds pretty easy, but I do have to write a program that is the same and runs on ALL cars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better first with a 'passed' variable as part of Cars and actually maybe rename Cars to Car as it represents just one car. It might help you visualize the problem better.

```
struct Car{
    int priority;
    int passed; // lets set this to 1 if passed
};
```

And an intersection structure

```
struct Intersection
{
    struct Car cars[4]; // let's give an intersection 4 cars
}
```

Set up the intersection structure with some cars, initializing their 'passed' variable to 0 meaning 'not passed'.

```
struct Intersection intersection;

// set the car priority
intersection.cars[0].priority = 2;
intersection.cars[1].priority = 1;
intersection.cars[2].priority = 3;
intersection.cars[3].priority = 0;

intersection.cars[0].passed = 0;
intersection.cars[1].passed = 0;
intersection.cars[2].passed = 0; /** Could do a loop here to initialize instead! */
intersection.cars[3].passed = 0;
```

You can use a loop, looping until all cars have passed

An example program (not terribly efficient) as I'm taking into account the possibility you are new to C and have probably not yet learned the likes of linked lists or pointers etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct Car{
        int priority;
        int passed;
    };

    // four cars per intersection
    struct Intersection{
        struct Car cars[4];
    };

    struct Intersection intersection;

    // set the car priority
    intersection.cars[0].priority = 2;
    intersection.cars[1].priority = 1;
    intersection.cars[2].priority = 3;
    intersection.cars[3].priority = 0;

    intersection.cars[0].passed = 0;
    intersection.cars[1].passed = 0;
    intersection.cars[2].passed = 0;
    intersection.cars[3].passed = 0;

    // keep looping until all cars passed
    while (!intersection.cars[0].passed ||
        !intersection.cars[1].passed ||   /* <--- this could be improved !! */
        !intersection.cars[2].passed ||
        intersection.cars[3].passed)
    {

        int best_priority = -1;
        int best_car_index = -1;

        // look for next car that can pass
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            // this car hasn't passed yet -- check priority
            if (!intersection.cars[i].passed)
            {
                           // if not found a car yet to pass or this car is better, then choose this one so far...                  
                if ((best_priority == -1) || (intersection.cars[i].priority < best_priority))
                {
                    best_car_index = i;
                    best_priority = intersection.cars[i].priority;
                }
            }
        }

        if (best_car_index == -1)
            break; // nothing found
        else
        {
            // set the car with best priority to 'passed'
            intersection.cars[best_car_index].passed = 1;

            printf("Car ID %d with priority %d just passed the intersection!\r\n", best_car_index, best_priority);
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Program output

```
Car ID 3 with priority 0 just passed the intersection!
Car ID 1 with priority 1 just passed the intersection!
Car ID 0 with priority 2 just passed the intersection!
Car ID 2 with priority 3 just passed the intersection!
```

The program probably doesn't do what you want but hopefully you'll be able to manipulate it the way you want.

(You could fill a new list instead of printing the data)

Comment: Hmm yes it could work for me, I do need to modify it a bit for what I need, but it's the closest to what I want so far. Thanks for the help mate